# jqeury.mmenu fires 'Syntax error, unrecognized expression' for href="#..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mmenu

When using href='#/' or any other href starting with '#' in **jquery.mmenu** plugin the following exception is fired:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <nav id="my-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/about/">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <div id="my-header">
      <a href="#my-menu">Open the menu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {$("#my-menu").mmenu();});
```

Although the execution is not affected and the page loads as expected in all cases the error is really annoying. 
See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t2q5gwr/1/): `Open the menu` -> `Home` see the console.

Posted an [issue](https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/382) on github but looking for any workarounds meanwhile

## **UDPATE**

The issue is [resolved](https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/382#event-347900349) in `5.3.1`

Comment: the fiddle doesn't show any errors

Comment: @depperm Go `Open the menu` -> `Home` than see console

Comment: I checked the console, using Chrome, no issues

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7i0xij No issues aswell (in Chrome), documented. What browser are you using?

Comment: Using 43.0.2357.124m + Firefox and IE happening on 3 dirrefent machines as well

Comment: On jsfiddle you have to switch to the good frame to check the result console : http://imgur.com/hsST0PY

Comment: Tried with firefox 36.0.4 (quite old): No issues at all. Updated Firefox to 37.0.1 : No issues aswell (apart jsfiddle errors). Does it stop the script execution or..?

Comment: @briosheje nope, the page is loaded as expected and the menu click works fine, just the nasty exception. FF 38 latest, pretty sure the same happens on older versions

Comment: @Nobe4 thank you, at least I'm not mad :)

Comment: I recommand exploring the fiddle script with a breakpoint to see the sizzle execution : http://imgur.com/L0EqX9I

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a sizzle specific error.

Look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rLzo0t1/).

```
console.log(Sizzle(".a"));
console.log(Sizzle("#/about/"));
```

This is the same error, i think it means that the selector is not valid.
Based on [This article](http://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/) I can confirm that the selector is not valid.

[image]

So here is your problem :)

Comment: Makes sence, `Sizzle("#/about/")` is definetely not a valid selector, but `<a href='#/something'>` does not ment to be selected from the do on this selector.  which means that the problem is in mmenu plugin, trying to make a selector out of href attribute. And I'm asking for any workarounds for this issue, while it's being addressed by plugin devs